# A keyboard with a UITextField

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield

I have a table listing some strings, and what I want is when I tap the add button on the navigation bar, a keyboard with a textField would jump up, so I can input a string in the textField, then when I tap the return key, the keyboard disappear as well as the textField, and the new string is added to the table.

I already make up a nib file with a toolBar containing a textField, and I just failed to go on.

How can I implement this idea? Use the inputAccessoryView? If so, that means the inputAccessoryView of the textField which belongs to the toolBar is gonna be the toolBar itself!

This seem kind of weird and I have not been able to make it work till now.

Or is there another way for this idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problems by using notification instead of `inputAccessoryView`.

There is a sample code in XCode called "KeyboardAccessory", and it gives a good example about using keyboard notifications!

Or custom a view with a tab, and set it as the textField's `inputAccessoryView`, that would also work!